# Is there a way to configure the DHCP options of a Windows 10 HyperV virtual switch?

Tags: dhcp, hyper-v, pxe

I want to install a PXE server, for test, on a VM machine in HyperV. For that i need to set some DHCP options.

Is there a way to configure those options for the virtual switch?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really, the default switch really can't be changed or deleted.  There are some hacks that may work, but are unsupported and will likely fail with each Windows Update.  For best results set up a small linux distro in a VM as a router/dns/dhcp client.  It will isolate your network and allow you custom config.  IPFire will run on 512MB of RAM. https://www.ipfire.org/

Comment: How about changing a custom Virtual Switch, not the default?